# How to select and flip a normal?

Tags: modeling

I've tried some things on the model when all is selected like these to no avail :

1. Mesh > Normals > Flip
2. Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside
3. Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Inside

I need to be able to select single normals and flip them... Is this possible? Also, I am using Blender "2.83.13.0 LTS"

[image: Particle Gun]

Comment: If you don't get consistent normals with all selected + recalculate, it's because you have non-manifold geometry.  Use "select non manifold" operation to get Blender to point out the problem areas.

Comment: "Select Non Manifold" seems to select the whole model actually !!

Comment: Disable "boundary" on the operator panel for it.

Comment: Sorry, IDK where to do that! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Select a plane in *edit mode* and press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> *-> Flip*